# KB4025339 update broke Visual Studio 2015/2017 and SSMS

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, visual-studio

After the installation of the KB4025339 update on July 11th, Visual Studio 2015/2017 and SQL Server Management Studio all fail to start.  The error message is "An exception was thrown by the target of an invocation."

- I'm running Windows 10 Professional. (OS Build 14393.1480)
- Extensive Googling provided no hits for this problem as relates to KB4025339. Several sites that mention this error message state that it can be caused by an excessively long PATH variable. That's not the issue here (yes I did try shortening the PATH).
- Running devenv.exe with the /Log parameter does produce a log file, but it contains only informational messages (no warnings or errors).
- No errors are logged in the Event Log.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio has no effect on the problem.
- Installing the same update on several other machines did not cause any issues.

I eventually got desperate and uninstalled KB4025339. Visual Studio and SSMS now work again.  I doubt this is a viable long-term solution though. I might try re-installing KB4025339 to see what happens, but at the moment being able to use these programs is more important.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any suggestions on other things I might try to diagnose the problem?

Comment: report the [issue to Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)

Comment: Just a note to say that you're not the only one. This update has broken TopSolid for me (specialist CAD software). I uninstalled it, which fixed the problem, but then when I restarted windows it automatically reinstalled it - and now TopSolid is fine but Excel won't start. They both did the same thing - you double-click the EXE/shortcut, then nothing happens. Looking in Task Manager, a process is open and using one full core of CPU (25% CPU load) but then nothing happens.